# Debugger interrupts even in try-catch block

Tags: c#, selenium-chromedriver

How do I stop VisualStudio from interrupting program's flow?

Normally, if you use `try-catch block`, then the `exception` will be handled automatically without bringing an attention to the user.
In my case - program's flow is interrupted by an `exception`.

It's worth mentioning, that my program continues to function even after I decide to `Continue` the execution.

These exceptions are troubling me:

> A first chance exception of type
>   '**OpenQA.Selenium.StaleElementReferenceException**' occurred in
>   WebDriver.dll Additional information: stale element reference: element
>   is not attached to the page document

and also

> **OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverTimeoutException**

which you see on the picture

[image]

Comment: Oh actually, I now see the check which says "break when this exception type is thrown" Seems like that is the root cause of my issue. I will not remove the question, still, because changing each and single exception is one thing. Another is - disabling all of them in batch. Why are these exceptions so different from the rest? :)

Comment: Debug -> Exceptions. There's a good chance you'll find it there.

Comment: I searched for it already - no luck. Maybe that is because Selenium comes as a separate reference for the project. i.e. these are not some native exceptions.

Comment: An update: even though I unchecked the checkbox - this exception keeps showing up... So, I need another solution.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer is quite obvious.
All you have to do is to add a new exception to list. Then Uncheck it. Done.